# remote XFCE4 chrome window is hidden

Tags: 16.04, xfce, remote-desktop, rdp

I start a remote desktop XFCE4 session where then I'm clicking the chrome shortcut. I can see with `ps` that chrome is started, but I don't see its window.

Why this happens?
How to bring to front the chrome's window?

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux utg353l 4.4.0-67-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 8 16:34:45 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I recommend you to avoid the problem by using [x2go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php).